# MariaDB ERROR 4161 (HY000): Unknown Data Type

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb

Getting an unknown data type error when I try to create tables with a foreign key. I am not sure if my syntax is wrong? The exact error message is: ERROR 4161 (HY000) at line 14: Unknown data type: 't_name', meaning the P1_Player table is where the error is being thrown.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS P1_Player;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS P1_Plays;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS P1_Coach;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS P1_Game;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS P1_Team;

create table P1_Team
       (t_name          varchar(20),
        primary key (t_name)
        );

create table P1_Player
       (fname           varchar(20),
        lname           varchar(20),
        DOB             date,
        jersey_#        int,
        t_name          varchar(20),
        primary key (fname, lname, DOB),
        foreign key (t_name) references P1_Team (t_name)
                on delete cascade
        );

create table P1_Coach
       (fname            varchar(20),
        lname            varchar(20),
        t_name           varchar(20),
        foreign key (t_name) references P1_Team (t_name)
                on delete cascade
        );

create table P1_Game
       (t_name           varchar(20),
        game_date         date,
        game_time         time,
        primary key (t_name, game_date, game_time),
        foreign key (t_name) references P1_Team (t_name)
                on delete cascade
        );
create table P1_Plays
       (t_name            varchar(20),
        game_date         date,
        game_time         time,
        primary key (t_name, game_date, game_time),
        foreign key (t_name, game_date, game_time) references P1_Game (t_name, game_date,    game_time)
                on delete cascade
        );
```

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? What makes you think that `jersey_#`  is a valid column name?

Comment: removing the pound sign solved the error thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in `jersey_#` on `create table P1_Player` you should use the back-quote (`) if you want to use special characters in mysql/mariadb column names :

```
create table P1_Player
       (fname           varchar(20),
        lname           varchar(20),
        DOB             date,
        `jersey_#`        int,
        t_name          varchar(20),
        primary key (fname, lname, DOB),
        foreign key (t_name) references P1_Team (t_name)
                on delete cascade
        );
```